# How can I exclude a specific element from inheriting CSS rules?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this CSS:

```
a {
  color:#19558D;
  padding:3px 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color:#D1E1EA;
  color:#19558D;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

It applies to all links, but what if I don't want it to apply to a specific link on the page? What can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can apply your own class or inline style to the link in question.

for example:

```
<a href="#" class="MyNewClass" />
```

or

```
<a href="#" style="color:red;" />
```

Answer (score 63):

There are two ways you can do this.

First way is to use the `:not()` selector and give your link that you don't want the styles applied to class:

```
a:not(.unstyled):hover {
  background-color:#D1E1EA;
  color:#19558D;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

However, the `:not()` selector is not supported in IE8 or less, so the second option is to give your unstyled links a class, and override those properties for that link with that class:

```
a.unstyled:hover {
  background-color:none;
  color:#000
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Obligatory albeit redundant "`:not()` is a CSS3 selector and there's lousy browser support" comment goes here.