# Don't include css styling on one specific input

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, input

While building angular reactive form it occurred to me that I should capitalize first letter on each input, so in my **css**, I wrote

```
   input {
      text-transform: capitalize;
   }
```

But in my html I have input for email and don't want to style that, how can I exclude that?

my html

```
                <div class="form-group" 
                  [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('FirstName')">
                    <label for="FirstName" class="control-label 
                   required">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="FirstName" class="form-control" 
                 formControlName="FirstName">

                </div>

        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('Email')">
           <label for="Email" class="control-label 
            required">Email</label>
           <input type="text" id="Email" class="form-control" 
           formControlName="Email"> 
         </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude a specific element from inheriting CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507253/how-can-i-exclude-a-specific-element-from-inheriting-css-rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Either add an additional class to the input element that you want to
  customize:

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" class="form-control myInput" 
         formControlName="FirstName">
```

**css**

```
.myInput{
          text-transform: capitalize;

}
```

- either

**CSS**

```
  #FirstName{
          text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

Comment: can I write some thing like this #FirstName #LastName { styling } ?

Comment: with a comma ',' : #FirstName, #LastName {, yes :)

Comment: You can add that class, i.e "myInput" , to any input that you want to be capitalized and put it in styles.css and use it project wide. (probably renaming it something for significant name, like "capText" :) )

Answer (score 3):

You can use the :not() pseudo-class.

```
input:not(#Email) {
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Refer [:not usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following style

`input:not([id="Email"]) {
      text-transform: capitalize;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a css class instead of defining tag as css.

**file.html**

```
   <div class="form-group" 
                      [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('FirstName')">
                        <label for="FirstName" class="control-label 
                       required">First name</label>
                        <input class="inputCss" type="text" id="FirstName" class="form-control" 
                     formControlName="FirstName">

                    </div>

            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('Email')">
               <label for="Email" class="control-label 
                required">Email</label>
               <input class="" type="text" id="Email" class="form-control" 
               formControlName="Email"> 
             </div>
```

**cssFile.css**

```
 .inputCss{
      tesxt-transform: capitalize;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should use correct `type`for your input elements.

Then you can style them accordingly.

```css
/* Directly */ 
input[type="text"] {
  text-transform: capitalize
}

/* or by exclusion */ 
input:not([type="email"]) {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="input type='text'" />
<input type="email" placeholder="input type='email'" />
```